# How does this piece of code written in C++ work?

Tags: c++, function, reference, variable-assignment

I tried executing the below code in GeekForGeeks. I am pasting the piece of code here. I have multiple questions i shall state them at last

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    static int y = 20;
    cout<<"\nAfter Assign\n"<<x<<"\n"<<y;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout <<"\nFun\n"<< fun();
    return 0;
}

Gives Output

After Assign
10
20
After Assign
30
20
Fun
30
```

and when i change the return variable to y as in the code below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    static int y = 20;
    cout<<"\nAfter Assign\n"<<x<<"\n"<<y;
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout <<"\nFun\n"<< fun();
    return 0;
}

Output is as follows:

After Assign
10
20
After Assign
10
30
Fun
30
```

Q1 : As seen in the output, I can see the value of x and y are printed as 10 and 20, during the first call. So fun()=30, has no effect? Where is the value 30 stored?

Q2 : when fun() =30 is assigned, what actually is the behaviour. Are they not assigned to variables inside fun()?

Q3 : Why is value of x 30, when it is returned and why is the value of y 30, when it is returned? What is really happening here.

Kindly provide your comments and inputs.

Comment: I dont understand the down-votes and close-votes, the question is clear and well written. It is a beginner question, but that is supposed to be ok, we were all there once.

Comment: @yms - Could be because we saw the same question earlier this week,

Comment: @BoPersson This should cause a "duplicate" marker, not a "too broad":

Comment: @BoPersson ah,that makes sense.

Comment: @Subramaniancv next time, dont ask the same question twice,  just edit your original question if you have more details to provide.

Comment: @yms i shall do that.. i was trying a program yesterday and i made more changes to it. Thought a new question would be better, because the doubts were new. I shall edit the old posts from now on. Thanks for the support..

Comment: @Tony I tried what u said and it gave the output


After Assign
10
20

After Assign
10
30

Fun
30

Comment: @CVS ah yes - sorry - my mistake... that last single line is coming from main itself....  Sorry for taking your time over nothing.  Cheers

Comment: @TonyD Not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1 : As seen in the output, I can see the value of x and y are printed as 10 and 20, during the first call. So fun()=30, has no effect? Where is the value 30 stored?

This is not correct:

```
cout<<"\nAfter Assign\n"<<x<<"\n"<<y;
```

it gets executed before assignment, your `int &fun()` function returns reference to x variable which after `fun` returns will get assigned.

> Q2 : when fun() =30 is assigned, what actually is the behaviour. Are they not assigned to variables inside fun()?

its assigned but after fun returns, behaviour is that static variable inside your function changes value

> Q3 : Why is value of x 30, when it is returned and why is the value of y 30, when it is returned? What is really happening here.

not sure If I understand, its 30 because you have assigned this value - `int &fun()` returns reference to x or y - variables. Since they are static you can do that - no UB here.

You can imagine for yourself that `fun() = 30;` behaves like `x = 30;` (or `y = 30`).

Answer (score 2):

Q1: the assignment happens *after* the function call, so the first call prints the original static values;

Q2: `fun() =30` assigns `30` to the value returned by `fun()`, that happens to be a reference to the variable `x` (`y` in the second version) that is *static* to `fun` which means its storage is persistent across calls to `fun`.

Q3: When `fun` returns, it returns a reference to the static variable `x`, so the assignment modifies the value of this variable. Had the returned value not be a reference, then the returned value would have be a copy, and the original value would not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

> So fun()=30 has no effect?

It has an effect: y now is 30!

Program starts, go into fun(). First time call results in init of x to 10 and y to 20. After that a reference to y is returned.

These reference is used to set y to 30.

Next call fun() prints out 10 and 30 which is exact what we expect.

Please read a beginner book for c++. Especially you have to read what a `reference` is.

Comment: Sorry, I commented on the changed version from the OP :-) Fixed that!

Answer (score 0):

`fun()` returns a reference to the variable returned.

In the first case, you are calling `fun()`, which prints `x` and `y` with a value of 10 and 20 as assigned first. Then you are assigning 30 to the return value of it (in this case, a reference to 'x').

So when calling `fun()` again, it prints 30 (for `x`, which we modified) and 20 for `y`, which we didn't.

The variables inside `fun()` are `static`, so once initialized they are not initialized again.

Now it's obvious why when you change your return variable to `y` you get that output